# Need extension cord with toggle for 2 lamps

Tags: electrical

Wife bought 2 lamps to go on mantle. There is a plug above mantle but lamps too high to reach rotary switch on lamps. How can I construct an extension cord from wall plug above mantle to plug lamps into and then add toggle switch that can be reached to turn both lamps on? Or anyone have a better remedy?

Comment: Keep it neat by using a "clapper" (clap-on, clap-off) instead of routing and positioning a physical switch in an easy-to-reach location.

Comment: Is having a cord-mounted switch resting on the mantle an option?

Comment: There is an assortment of this type of device: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000KKND86/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_JAlgAbCCQJKHT look closely it’s not an extension cord, it’s a remote switch.   The real answer tho, is call an electrician and have these lights wired in with a proper switch.

Comment: Is the receptacle (plug) also too high to reach?

Comment: Yes. And there is a picture hung over it.

Comment: A cord mounted switch on the mantle is an option. Can these be purchased?

Comment: I’m also interested in remote control possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these, available at your local hardware shop:

[image]

Comment: Good idea but plug (receptacle) is too high to reach and behind a picture.